Custom fullScreenCover animation
Is it possible to add a custom animation to a fullScreenCover? The default animation has been disabled but I am struggling in finding a way to add a custom animation.
I guess that transaction.disablesAnimations = true disables any animation that is added, but I didn't find any other way to disable the default animation.
I know that there are alternative ways of implementing something like this (fallback to UIKit or using an overlay), but it would be interesting if it could be done using a fullScreenCover.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresentingFullScreenCover = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show FullScreenCover") {
            isPresentingFullScreenCover = true
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.black)
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentingFullScreenCover) {
            FullScreenCoverView()
        }
        .transaction { transaction in
            transaction.disablesAnimations = true
        }
    }
}

struct FullScreenCoverView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}


You can put the two views in a ZStack and apply a custom transition to the view on the top. Other than that, I don't think this can be done in pure SwiftUI.

Yeah, there are for sure alternatives in solving this, but it would be interesting to know if this can be solved with the fullScreenCover.

I’m pretty sure you can’t.

You have successfully disabled the normal transition. So all you need to do now is:

hide the presentation background
show and hide the content using your own animated transition.

The animation that you add can be triggered by toggling a flag in .onAppear and .onDisappear:
struct FullScreenCoverView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var isShowing = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            if isShowing {
                Button("Dismiss") {
                    withAnimation {
                        isShowing = false
                    } completion: {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.background)
                .transition(.scale.animation(.easeInOut))
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .presentationBackground(.clear)
        .onAppear { isShowing = true }
        .onDisappear { isShowing = false }
    }
}


